# Qt Automotive Embedded Cluster (ICP)

Tags: qt, user-interface, embedded

I am new to Qt and was curious if we can develop HMI for a Cluster(Instrument Cluster Panel) using Qt.
Can someone share a demo? 
I might be in a wrong place to post this question, please don't flag.

I am looking for Examples/Demo in QT 5. (5.3.1)

Comment: Sure, you can easily implement pretty much any kind of widget/display with Qt Quick these days. It's used a lot for custom interfaces already and has seen adoption in the IVI market.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this widgets on `Qt Apps` website:

http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/AnalogWidgets?content=87780

As you can see there are many beautiful widgets. For example:

[image]

There is also `Qwt`: well documented tool with a lot of different technical widgets.

http://qwt.sourceforge.net/index.html

[image]

From [here](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/controlscreenshots.html)

Comment: @Chernobly I really loved your reply. I appreciate it. Can you help me with QT 5.3.1 (QT5). I the example you gave me was with QT4

Comment: @talktomevintron Unfortunately I still doesn't work with Qt 5.3, I work with Qt 5.2.0 and I used Qwt absolutely successfully (to install it, I used manual on site, also there are a few video lessons). AnalogWidgets I didn't use, but author wrote that `Qt5 and Qt4 supported`

Answer (score 1):

A good example is a dial-type control which combines Image elements with `Rotation` transforms and `SpringAnimation` behaviors to produce an interactive speedometer-type dial. You can find the example in the installed Qt directory in `Examples/Qt-5.3/quick/customitems/dialcontrol`.